# How to fix 'ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_dataframe' from 'pandas.api.types' error in ML using Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

Please Someone explain this error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tz0E.png)

it's a simple command but it's now working I had taken a random matrix of 5x4 with (A,B,C,D,E) and (W,X,Y,Z) and took the command df['W']>0 however there was an error I have attached it's image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't copy images of your code, instead copy it into your question so that others that reproduce the error themselves. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)